# updating ng-model from ng-value directive

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I have a situation where I have couple of readonly fields in the form like with others to show the problem

You can see the las two inputs are `readonly` and they are calculated inputs where total debit is calculated by `totalDebit` function on `$scope` and total credit is calculated by `totalCredit()` function on the `$scope`. The problem is inputs only reflect ng-model values which is zero for both inputs and does not take value from calculating functions. A simplified controller is

```
app.controller('myController', ['$scope' ,function($scope){
$scope.credit = 0;
$scope.debit = 0;
$scope.debitSum = 0;
$scope.creditSum = 0;

$scope.totalCredit = function(){
   return $scope.credit + 200; //just to show that it is calculated field
}

$scope.totalDebit = function(){
   return $scope.debit + 200; //just to show that it is calculated field
}

}]);
```

If you remove `ng-model` directive from readonly inputs they will assume their values from `totalDebit` and `totalCredit` functions respectively. But I want them to use values from functions and also update `$scope` properties of `totalDebit` and `totalCredit`. Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/B99T5cp4qBa1CK93VyT4?p=preview) for this code

Answer (score 3):

Should not be answer here *(Why the ng-value is not doing what expected)*:

#### [ngValue](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue)

> Binds the given expression to the value of **`<option>`** or **`input[radio]`**, so that when the element is selected, the ngModel of that element is set to the bound value.

And that is not our case...

> Because, the `ngValue` is triggered on CHANGE. When we select radio or some option in the `<select>`

So, `ng-value` is not the proper setting in this scenario.

We can adjust it like this:

```
<input name="totalDebit" value="{{totalDebit()}}" readonly="" />
<input name="totalCredit" value="{{totalCredit()}}" readonly="" />
```

See [updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9RqHUpyKm2ehjFD12kFF?p=preview)

Comment: Yeah I read that to. What should you use for readonly inputs? ng-model throws an exception.

Comment: One way could be seen in my extended answer

Comment: @RadimKöhler your answer will precisely show the calculated value in readonly inputs but it will not bind it to any property on the scope. I need that too

Comment: It is this way. If we need some calculation, we have to observe the parts which are included. That is what the `value="{{totalDebit()}}"` do. It is observing all the parts and until the result is "stable", its value is not changing, it is beeing re-invoked. That means, that part of that method could be setting the result into the `$scope.creditSum = ...`. That's it. In fact, this would be to solution in the background using `$scope.$watch()`. The View is just assigning that watch for us. Hope this help ;) Good luck with Angular